# Is there a simpler to add multiple classes to different divs jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fading out a different divs on click for certain period of time at the moment I have a single function for each operation, I have named them .fade-a, .fade-b, .fade-c etc. Surely there must be a better way to do this as at the moment I just have along list that seems bloated.

Sorry if I am not explaining this very well I don't use much jQuery.

Thanks

```
$('.fade-a').click(function() {
    $('.fade-a').addClass('fade');
    var delay = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".fade-a").removeClass("fade");
    }, 1000)
});
$('.fade-b').click(function() {
    $('.fade-b').addClass('fade');
    var delay = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".fade-b").removeClass("fade");
    }, 1000)

});
$('.fade-c').click(function() {
    $('.fade-c').addClass('fade');
    var delay = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".fade-c").removeClass("fade");
    }, 1000)

});
$('.fade-d').click(function() {
    $('.fade-d').addClass('fade');
    var delay = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".fade-d").removeClass("fade");
    }, 1000)

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="width33 site-top">
    <span>
        <img class="info-block-toggle-a fade-a site-overlay size-auto" src="images/i-am-the-cosmos.jpg" alt="" />
    </span>
</div>
<div class="width33 site-middle">
    <span>
        <img class="info-block-toggle-b fade-b site-overlay size-auto" src="images/dorje.jpg" alt="" />
    </span>
</div>
<div class="width33 site-bottom">
    <span>
        <img class="info-block-toggle fade-c site-overlay size-auto" src="images/harvey.png" alt="" />
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fade-a, .fade-b, .fade-c, .fade-d, .fade-e, .fade-f, .fade-g, .fade-h, .fade-i {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
.fade-a.fade, .fade-b.fade, .fade-c.fade, .fade-d.fade, .fade-e.fade, .fade-f.fade, .fade-g.fade, .fade-h.fade, .fade-i.fade {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
}
```

Comment: Usually this is simple with a single function. If you also show your HTML, the answer will become clear :)

Comment: I could not get your CSS to work in the JSFiddle without the images, so I just substituted a green border so you can see it work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This enhances @TrueBlueAssie answer to comply with a more "simpler" way as requested by the OP. But "simpler" in this context represents a more meaningful and understandable code inside the click handler, trying to leverage more jquery and JS coolness.

I will be using `.makeme` -> `.big` classes, instead of `.fademe` -> `.fade`.

First lets go and use jquery queue inside each handler to handle proper execution:

```
$( ".makeme" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
  var $element = $( event.currentTarget );
  $({})
    .queue(function( next ) {
      $element.addClass( "big" );
      next();
    })
    .delay( 1000 )
    .queue(function( next ) {
      $element.removeClass( "big" );
      next();
    });
});
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/kxhpu4z6/

And that's it.

We can even play a little bit with a factory to create each queue callback that executes a single jQuery method and handles the `next` call for us:

```
// queueCallback by Fagner Brack (MIT Licensed)
// Create a callback for jquery queue mechanism that executes a single
// jquery method once resolved.
function queueCallback( element, method ) {
  var methodArgs = [].slice.call( arguments, 2 );
  var $element = $( element );
  return function( next )  {
    method.apply( $element, methodArgs );
    next();
  };
}
```

The click handler is now written like this:

```
$( ".makeme" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
  var element = event.currentTarget;
  $({})
    .queue( queueCallback( element, $.fn.addClass, "big" ) )
    .delay( 1000 )
    .queue( queueCallback( element, $.fn.removeClass, "big" ) );
});
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/kxhpu4z6/2/

The snippets can be modified to be adapted for each desired behavior after clicking in the element or after the 1s delay has ended.

---

**EDIT: DO NOT USE THIS**

I discovered custom queue using plain objects in jquery constructor was [**NEVER SUPPORTED**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1886#issuecomment-66921062).

It was never documented and plain object supported is being deprecated in jquery 3.0. So if you need a proper jquery queue you can use or create a custom plugin for that purpose and with a decent syntax.

Comment: I am genuinely shocked you feel this is a more maintainable solution. The final version is longer, almost unreadable (and adds a custom function to make it work) and has greater runtime overheads. K.I.S.S. is a sensible rule. Go figure :)

Comment: Verbosity is not always synonymous of lack of maintainability, this is false syllogism. It is not unreadable, unless you don't understand jquery or javascript, if you worry about abstraction leaks between Javascript and jQuery you would not be using jquery because it is not supposed to work without JS knowledge. If team maintainability is a must, one or two unit tests could make it more stable.

Comment: It doesn't add a custom function to make it work. You can use the first example that make it clear the intent, instead of using unnamed arguments of setTimeout. The last approach is just in case you want to use a pattern that reduces the number of function declarations, that just depends on your environment and if you want to use that specific behavior several times inside the handler or somewhere else, then you can put it in some kind of "utils" file.

Comment: Everything has runtime overheads, but you should not waste time for useless optimizations. In most requirements, maintainability should be done in favor of early optimizations. Yes, K.I.S.S. is a sensible rule. But simplicity doesn't mean just ignore different ways to achieve the same result. By the way, I never said this is a more maintanable solution, it is more scalable.

Comment: Anyway, it is not supposed to replace your solution, in this specific context your solution seems to be more adequate. I don't know why the OP changed the correct answer oO

Comment: I have heard (and disregard) most of those arguments over 35 years of coding, but the fact remains you need to have knowledge of `jCallback` in order to read the code. Writing simple/readable/maintainable code is more difficult, but certainly a target to aim for :)

Comment: Well you can understand `jCallback` method just by understanding javascript and jquery queue mechanism. A comment also can make things much clearer if that's an issue. And by the way, you are missing the point here, the actual answer lies in the first example, which is much more meaningful than using "this" variables and setTimeout unnamed arguments. The first example make it clear the intent, dont you agree with that? The last example was also to abstract the "next" to avoid repeating for every callback declaration, not required for this answer specifically, but left here for posterity.

Comment: By the way, I just edited `jCallback` to `queueCallback` and added a comment explaining what the method does. I am pretty sure that's understandable enough, but if one don't understand what the method does, then the first example could be used instead. The problem is that using the second example will make the developer repeat code, which may not be ideal when the queue gets more complex (but still is much better than using lots of setTimeouts throughout the anonymous callback and having to store everything in variables at the top of the function).

Comment: Forgive me for chiming in, and maybe it's that I've eaten too much food today, but this just seems overly engineered for the one-off task the OP has at hand. Yeah, ok, it's understandable and everything, but I would not want to write something this heavy just for the simple eye-candy effect the OP wanted. This way does not feel simpler, and I really don't see how it's more scalable than TrueBlue's answer. Just my $0.02.

Comment: @Cory
TrueBlue's initially had the accepted answer. I just wrote this one because TrueBlue's commented it wasn't possible to use jquery queue in his solution, but then the OP changed the accepted answer later and TrueBlue's removed his comments, taking away all the context of why I created this in the first place...

Answer (score 5):

Use the same class on all of them (e.g. `fademe`) and do this:

```
$('.fademe').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('fade');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.removeClass("fade");
    }, 1000)
});
```

Code snippet:

```js
$('.fademe').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass('fade');
  var delay = setTimeout(function() {
    $this.removeClass("fade");
  }, 1000)
});
```

```css
.fade {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="width33 site-top">
  <span>
        <img class="info-block-toggle-a fademe site-overlay size-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF?text=1" alt="" />
    </span>
</div>
<div class="width33 site-middle">
  <span>
        <img class="info-block-toggle-b fademe site-overlay size-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/00FF00/FFFFFF?text=1" alt="" />
    </span>
</div>
<div class="width33 site-bottom">
  <span>
        <img class="info-block-toggle fademe site-overlay size-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/FFFFFF?text=1" alt="" />
    </span>
</div>
```

**Notes:**

- Inside a click event, `this` is the DOM element clicked. `$(this)` is a jQuery object of the same element. You need to keep a reference to the original `this`, e.g. in a var, as the `this` inside the `setTimeout` callback is different.
- Prefixing jQuery variable names with `$` is just a common standard. Call it whatever you like :)
- I used a green border to show your `fade` class as images were not available.

Comment: Do not use $this inside a callback, use the variable name representing the meaning, the recommended is to use the function arguments instead of relying on "this". delay var is not used, so there is no need to set it. Use queue and "delay" to achieve this using jquery without having to handle "setTimeout" by itself.

Comment: Negative, you can use jquery queue pattern for any queue solution, it doesn't necessarly means it should be restricted to the "fx" type queue. See my answer.

Comment: @Fagner Brack: Granted their var delay was obsolete (now removed).